# Click button under canvas in HTML

Tags: html, canvas, click

I have a button in html.

Button is partially covered by canvas (with transparent background) and I can't click it in area covered by canvas.

[image]

It is very complicated form rich in graphic and moving these things will require a lot of work.

Is is possible to make canvas "invisible" for mouse click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a z-index on the button and canvas.

```
button, canvas {
    position: relative;
}

button {
    z-index: 1;
}

canvas {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make button `position:relative`. It will allow you to click on button.

```css
button {
    position: relative;
}

canvas {
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<button>click</button>
<canvas width="100" height="100" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use z-index in your css to apply a z-order. [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something with z-index?

Button:
    z-index: 1;

Canvas:
    z-index: 0;